# Realtime push notification golang

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

I want to implement a real time notification feature in my web application. I am following this example "https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat". I need the server (hub) to get messages, it needs to push those messages to individual clients based on some form of ID. how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried? Can you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain how it did not work as intended?

Comment: @Adrian-I have the sample Chat application. Not sure how to only send the msg to certain users. Right now the msg gets sent to all clients connected.

Comment: So where's your code?

Answer (score 1):

From the sample you mentioned:

```
    case message := <-h.broadcast:
        for client := range h.clients {
            select {
            case client.send <- message:
            default:
                close(client.send)
                delete(h.clients, client)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the case where a message is broadcasted to all clients. As you can see it loops over all registered clients and sends the message to every single one of them.

To preserve this functionality we will simply add another case: send to a single client.

```
    case message := <-h.clientMessage:
        for client := range h.clients {
            if message.ClientID == client.ID {
                select {
                case client.send <- message:
                default:
                    close(client.send)
                    delete(h.clients, client)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This should give you an idea. The rest I leave up to you.

Note: my sample code can be optimised by e.g. using a `map[clientID]Client` to access the client directly.

Comment: @TehSphinX- How Do i sent the Client.ID when the connection is created? I need the Client.ID to match a session value

Comment: can I send the session Id in my cookie when I connect? so the map can be map[SessionID]client ?

Comment: SessionID (or ClientID) comes from the server, not the client. When a new Client connects the server should assign it a unique ID. You might be ably to use some SessionID that is already created by whatever server you use.

Comment: @TehSphinX-How do I determine what websocket belongs to what user so I can assign the websocket the sessionID

Comment: To answer this one would have to know your use case and your setup, what do you want to achieve? etc. If every client has a username the first thing they could send after connecting is their username. Since each connection is handled in a separate goroutine you can assign the username to your client. Maybe register the client to the global map only if the username arrived -- with username as key. (Make sure you use some protection for global map or use `syncmap.Map{}`).